# Setting up ActiveMQ with Journaled MySQL JDBC Persistence

Tags: mysql, persistence, activemq-classic

I'm running ActiveMQ 5.5.1 and having issues getting journaled JDBC persistence configured.  Using [the example here](http://fusesource.com/docs/esb/4.3/amq_persistence/FuseMBPersistJDBCJournaled.html), I get the following XML validation error:

```
./activemq console xbean:my-activemq.xml

Java Runtime: Sun Microsystems Inc. 1.6.0_29 /home/aj/jdk1.6.0_29/jre
  Heap sizes: current=253440k  free=250641k  max=253440k
    JVM args: -Xms256M -Xmx256M -Dorg.apache.activemq.UseDedicatedTaskRunner=true -Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging.properties -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dactivemq.classpath=/home/aj/apache-activemq-5.5.1/conf; -Dactivemq.home=/home/aj/apache-activemq-5.5.1 -Dactivemq.base=/home/aj/apache-activemq-5.5.1
ACTIVEMQ_HOME: /home/aj/apache-activemq-5.5.1
ACTIVEMQ_BASE: /home/aj/apache-activemq-5.5.1
Loading message broker from: xbean:my-activemq.xml

INFO | Refreshing org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1@13f3045: startup date [Thu Dec 22 07:49:17 EST 2011]; root of context hierarchy
ERROR: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to execute start task.
Reason: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
Error creating bean with name 'org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerService#0' defined in class path resource [my-activemq.xml]:
Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException:
Failed to convert property value of type 
'org.apache.activemq.store.journal.JournalPersistenceAdapter' to required type 
'org.apache.activemq.store.PersistenceAdapterFactory' for property 'persistenceFactory'; 
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 
[org.apache.activemq.store.journal.JournalPersistenceAdapter] to required type 
[org.apache.activemq.store.PersistenceAdapterFactory] for property 'persistenceFactory': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

I've reviewed [the published schema](http://activemq.apache.org/config/1.0/core/activemq-core-5.4.0-schema.html#journaledJDBC), but it appears to be completely different than this example, so clearly one of the two sources is out of sync.  Can anyone please share their working persistence configuration using Journaled JDBC with MySQL?

Here's the relevant sections of my configuration:

```
<bean id="mysql-ds" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/activemq?relaxAutoCommit=true"/>
    <property name="username" value="activemq"/>
    <property name="password" value="activemq"/>
    <property name="maxActive" value="200"/>
    <property name="poolPreparedStatements" value="true"/>
</bean>

  <persistenceFactory>
    <journaledJDBC journalLogFiles="5" dataDirectory="${activemq.base}/activemq-data" dataSource="#mysql-ds"/>
  </persistenceFactory>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try setting your persistence adapter with the following configuration:

```
<persistenceFactory>
    <journalPersistenceAdapterFactory journalLogFiles="5" dataDirectory="${activemq.base}/data" dataSource="#mysql-ds">
    </journalPersistenceAdapterFactory>
</persistenceFactory>
```

It worked for me, but be aware about the disadvantages of journals if you plan to use failover - they simply do not work together (there is no copy of your journal on a slave broker). After consideration we decided to use a sql server persistence without journaling and it worked just fine for the failovers on both publishers and subscribers.

Comment: Thanks, will try this.  Failover is definitely a concern, but in reading about this on AMQ site, it sounds like JDBC w/out journaling is much slower.  What is your traffic like:  steady or intermittent?  What are your peak and avg volumes?

Comment: Our system is not in production yet, but we are not expecting high volume of messages. At the peaks we expect 1000 messages/sec and our performance tests did not register even 40% cpu load with such traffic. For us the most important is reliability and guarantee that messages is sent/received when it needs to - without information loss, which is not tolerated.

Comment: I guess it's all a matter of perspective.  To me, 1000/sec is pretty substantial. However if it's not a sustained volume, then I would be interested in what you expect your average to be?

Comment: It's hard to tell, production will show us :) I would say we will have less than 100/sec in a normal operation.

Comment: A couple of more questions about your architecture, if you don't mind...are you doing replication at the db level or the broker level?  Also, are your db servers running on the same hardware as your brokers?  Lastly...what is the latency/distance between your master and your slave?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by replication. We use MSSQL server for persistence and run it on Windows Cluster; yes, brokers run on the same hardware as db - it is good for persistence performance; right now they co-located so the latency does not exist pretty much.